# Can't authenticate to Slack with passport-slack

Tags: passport.js, slack

I'm implementing "Slack authentication" with `passport-slack`. I only want to use `incoming-webhook`. I have set up 'incoming-webhook' but I got the error below:

> Unapproved permissions requested
>   incoming-webhook

The code:

```
const SlackStrategy = require('passport-slack').Strategy
passport.use(
  new SlackStrategy(
    {
      clientID: config.slack.client_id,
      clientSecret: config.slack.client_secret,
      scope: ['incoming-webhook'],
      skipUserProfile: true   
    },
    (req, profile, done) => {
        // slack data
    }
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set up scope here.

```
app.get('/auth/slack', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('slack', { scope: 'incoming-webhook' })(req, res, next)
})
```

Comment: Why? Can you provide enough detail to explain your reasoning to future readers who might have the same problem?